# Angular-cli - Cannot serve project after updates

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, angular-cli

I have updated both `npm`, `node` and `angular-cli` to the latest versions. Now, when I run the `ng serve` command in my existing working project, it gives the error below

```
ERROR in ./src/main.ts
Module build failed: TypeError: Cannot read property 'newLine' of undefined
    at Object.getNewLineCharacter (/home/bunyamin/WebstormProjects/c3dp/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:8062:20)
    at Object.createCompilerHost (/home/bunyamin/WebstormProjects/c3dp/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:44978:26)
    at Object.ngcLoader (/home/bunyamin/WebstormProjects/c3dp/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/loader.js:202:31)
 @ multi webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:4200 ./src/main.ts
```

I also noticed that when I run `npm run start` command, which is `ng serve` in the `package.json`, it say `Environment configuration does not contain "source" entry.` which is changed in new version of `angular-cli`. I suspect that the `npm` does not know about the new version of `angular-cli` but is it possible?

Can anyone who faced this problem before help me to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove your `node_modules`, then run `npm cache clean` and after it `re-install` them. It's all about `newLine` error.

What about `angular-cli`, if you work with newest version (`@angular/cli`), you need also to install it globally